Is there a way to make sure that "Windows_run()" imported from WindowsAccessBridge has completed running?
Basically, I'm developing a WPF app that uses WindowsAccessBridge.dll to list all active java windows. When I'm initializing my Java Automation class, I call the imported Windows_run() method:
[DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static void Windows_run();

Then, all window handles are retrieved in another part of my project and, for each handle, I call the following:
public IElement? FindWindowFromHandle(IntPtr handle)
{
    if (IsJavaWindow(handle) != 1)
        return null;
    unsafe
    {
        if (GetAccessibleContextFromHWND(handle, out Int32 VmID, out IntPtr javaWindowHandle) && javaWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    return new JavaElement(VmID, javaWindowHandle);
    }
    return null;
}

The problem is, the first time the method is called, IsJavaWindow() returns 0 even for handles that are indeed corresponding to java elements. If I then call the same method again, using the same handle and without changing anything else, it actually works as intended.
After a lot of debugging, my only logical conclusion is that the first time FindWindowFromHandle() is called, my Java Automation class hasn't properly initialized yet. Unfortunately, Windows_run() is void, so it appears there's no way to confirm it has loaded as expected.
I've tried a few workarounds that do seem to fix the problem, such as adding a button that fires FindWindowFromHandle() instead of calling it directly after initialization, or opening a MessageBox right before the first call. However, I don't want to depend on some arbitrary way of waiting. I need to make sure that it will search for java windows only after it has properly loaded. Is there any way to do that?
